# Find the vector normal to a curve at some point

Tags: vectors

I want to find the vector normal to the curve $x=3/4-y^2$ at the point (0,$\sqrt{3}/2)$ I know that the tangent line at point (0,$\sqrt{3}/2)$ is (1)y-$\sqrt{3}/2 = -1/ \sqrt{3} (x-0). $ I'm guessing that the normal vector $n_1$ = -1/$\sqrt{3}$ $\hat{i}$ + $\hat{j}$. Am I correct? I really have no idea how to find the vector normal to a curve.  I got the signs for the normal vector from the signs of the slope and the value of y of the tangent line equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1=-2yy'$, which gives $y'=-\frac{1}{2y}$.

Thus, a slop of the  normal it's $2\cdot\frac{\sqrt3}{2}=\sqrt3$.

Thus, the equation of the normal it's $y-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}=\sqrt3(x-0)$ or $y=\sqrt3x+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$.

An equation of the tangent it's indeed, $$y-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}x$$ or
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt3}x+y-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}=0,$$ 
which gives a vector normal $\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\vec{i}+\vec{j}$.

Comment: wow, i always converted to slope intercept to find normal lines, but i always knew that ax+by+cz+d=0 had the orthogonal vector (a,b,c) . thanks for helping me make the connection! the orthogonal vector would be (a,b) and then we would normalize it

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(x,y) : = x + y^2 -3/4 = 0$;

Normal $\vec n$ to $F(x,y) = c$:

$\vec n = \nabla F(x,y) =$

$( \frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y})   =  (1,2y)$.

At $(0, √3/2) :$

$ \vec n = (1, √3) = \vec i + √3 \vec j$.